# Vue Devtools not working locally

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-devtools

`Vue Devtools` works on all demos/examples online but not on my local pages. Even with the following, the `Vue Devtools` icon remains gray ("Vue.js not detected"). Why?

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script>    
    Vue.config.devtools = true;
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not able to recreate this. What browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add at-least 1 instance of vue, for the devtools to detect it. So, do:

```
new Vue({el: '#app'})
```

Answer (score 14):

The Vue source you are using there looks to be minimized / production build to me. You need to use the non minimized / non-production build.  Try https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.15/vue.js instead.

Also if you are working with local files i.e. accessing a page like `file://...` then "you need to check "Allow access to file URLs" for this extension in Chrome's extension management panel." see https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools

Comment: This was also the issue I was having. Enabling the setting allowed the extension to work as expected

Comment: They should set "Allow access to file URLs" to true as default.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to refresh the browser first.

If didn't work, make sure that if you're compiling CSS and JavaScript to have have development compilation for both not a compilation for production with minified files

If at least **one file is minified for prod**, **devtools will not show up**